# I want to build my army, but i need money. What to do?

Tags: warfare

Everything is ok but no money.

If you want to ask why to create an army, there are many reasons so don't ask. (or ask me on discord. peze#7418)

So how to get big money; to enter the stock market?  gambling?  or going into illegal business? or legal business?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112399/discussion-on-question-by-sirgeneral-i-want-to-build-my-army-but-i-need-money).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout, say https://www.tni.org/en/publication/the-revolutionary-armed-forces-of-colombia-farc-and-the-illicit-drug-trade, which talks about how an army with no official income is funded.

Spoiler alert. It's drug dealing.

Grow drugs. Sell drugs. Buy guns. Recruit poor people. Pay with drug money. Fight war.

Answer (score 0):

### Actually, you don't really need money to enlist an army

You could just *promise* them money, or rather spoils of conquest. That may be enough to motivate them.

Or you *promise them survival*, perhaps not even of themselves but of their families. They need to join your army because the alternative is worse, with an impending army of doom just beyond the horizon.

In actual fact, many armies aren't very highly paid today - you could probably earn much more in private industry, or pretty much in any other government job. So money is rarely a driving motivation for people to enlist.

Of course, sometimes people enlist in an army simply because they don't have the skills, or mindset, to do anything else. You could also rely on this too.

Comment: you are wrong. if there is no money then;no food, no salary, no medicine, no defense, no attack, no helicopter, tank, howitzer, jet planes, no propaganda, no power!  this would probably be an army that died before it was born.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional method for a government to pay for its excesses, at least since about 1950, is to just print more money.

This is one of the perceived advantages of modern fiat currency -- since it doesn't require maintaining a reserve of some precious material or goods, it's easy to expand the money supply.  In American history, the Second World War was mostly financed by issuing bonds -- borrowing money -- because the United States was still technically on a gold standard, even though citizens weren't allowed to own gold beyond jewelry quantity.  The latter part of the Viet Nam conflict, by contrast, were financed by simply spending money they didn't have (after the Nixon administration finally finished killing off the gold reserve requirements).  "Running the printing presses" was the term often used.

The down side of this is, when done too much, it causes inflation, where prices and wages both rises (prices first, enthusiastically, and wages only later, kicking and screaming) -- but economists apparently consider too-low inflation to be a bad thing these days.

If you're not using fiat currency, it can be (from the POV of the government) even worse, as you can wind up with the government owing lots and lots of money to those who were wealthy enough to finance your war by buying your bonds (lending you money at interest).  Several governments in Renaissance Europe were bankrupted this way; others took to persecuting the bankers to prevent foreclosure when they couldn't pay up.